# CloudFormation stack deployment fails when adding a bucket policy and EventBridge notifications to a S3 bucket with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

CloudFormation stack deployment fails intermittently when adding a bucket policy (PutBucketPolicy) and EventBridge notifications (PutBucketNotification) to a S3 bucket with CDK due to race condition.

```
Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Error: An error occurred (OperationAborted) when calling the PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation: A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. Please try again.. See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream: 2023/10/17/[$LATEST]9f69597966xxxxa8449646270045 (RequestId: 2xx08c-74ad-4317-8a30-83xxxf2dc9)
```

Below is my CDK code of using S3 Bucket construct with `eventBridgeEnabled: true` and adding the policy after creating the bucket.

```js
export class S3Bucket extends s3.Bucket {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: S3BucketProperties) {
    super(scope, id, {
      ...props,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      encryption: s3.BucketEncryption.KMS,
      encryptionKey: props.encryptionKey,
      eventBridgeEnabled: true,
    });
  }
}
```

```js
this.s3Bucket = new S3Bucket(this, 'bucket', {
      encryptionKey,
    });


this.s3Bucket.addToResourcePolicy(
      createS3BucketSSLRequestsOnlyPolicyStatement(
        this.s3Bucket.bucketArn
      )
    );
```

Any fix or workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/16811) on the cdk git with policy and notification conflicts. Although the issue is still open, there is a workaround for your specific use case.

[This comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/16811#issuecomment-1787882066) provides the full code sample. The important part is that you add a dependency between your notifications and your bucket policy, so the notifications will only be added once the policy has finished being added.

```
this.s3Bucket.node.findChild('Notifications').node.addDependency(this.s3Bucket.node.findChild('Policy'))
```