# How can I add dependency on deploying s3 bucket policy and adding event notification in same stack via CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I am using AWS CDK to deploy s3 bucket. The code I have is as below. It deploys a s3 bucket with some permission configuration, then add an existing SNS topic as the event notification on that bucket.

```
const bucket = new BaseS3Bucket(this, "bucket", {
      versioned: true,
      enforceSSL: true,
      bucketName: this.bucketName,
      blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
      accessControl: options.setAccessControl !== false ? s3.BucketAccessControl.PRIVATE : undefined,
      publicReadAccess: false,
      encryption: s3.BucketEncryption.KMS_MANAGED,
      serverAccessLogsBucket: logBucket,
      serverAccessLogsPrefix: 'deployment-logs',
      lifecycleRules: [
        {
          id: 'NonCurrentVersionRule',
          enabled: true,
          noncurrentVersionExpiration: cdk.Duration.days(BucketCdkStack.NON_CURRENT_VERSION_EXPIRATION_DAY),
        },
      ],
    });
    const topic = cdk.aws_sns.Topic.fromTopicArn(
      this,
      "topic",
      topicArn,
    );
bucket.policy?.node.addDependency(topic);
    bucket.addEventNotification(s3.EventType.OBJECT_REMOVED_DELETE, new cdk.aws_s3_notifications.SnsDestination(topic));
```

The problem I have is I got a deployment error: `Resource handler returned message: "A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. Please try again.`

It says there are multiple operations tried to deploy at the same time which conflict with each other. When examining the cloud trail, I found there are two events happened at the same time period, one is `PutBucketPolicy`, the other is `PutBucketNotification`.

The `PutBucketPolicy` event is to add below policy on the bucket:

```
"bucketPolicy": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Condition": {
                        "Bool": {
                            "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    "Action": "s3:*",
                    "Resource": [
                        "arn:aws:s3:::xxx",
                        "arn:aws:s3:::xxx/*"
                    ],
                    "Effect": "Deny",
                    "Principal": {
                        "AWS": "*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
```

The `PubBucketNotification` event is:

```
"NotificationConfiguration": {
            "xmlns": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/",
            "TopicConfiguration": {
                "Event": "s3:ObjectRemoved:Delete",
                "Topic": "xxx"
            }
        },
        "notification": "",
        "bucketName": "xxx",
        "Host": "xxx"
```

I believe that two concurrency operations conflict each other because they are targeting on the same bucket. Is there a way to add a `depend` on those two operations?

Comment: This is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77320288/cloudformation-stack-deployment-fails-when-adding-a-bucket-policy-and-eventbridg Consider opening an issue on github

Comment: A GitHub bug report already exists:  [@aws-cdk/aws-s3: CloudFormation stack deployment fails intermittently when adding a bucket policy and EventBridge notifications](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/27600)